# Console.ReadLine not working on Task's ContinueWith

Tags: c#, task, console-application

Let's say I have this piece of code:

```
var tasks = new Task<string>[] { ToStringAsync(1) };
Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(r => Console.WriteLine(r.Result.First()));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Where `ToStringAsync` has the following implementation:

```
private Task<string> ToStringAsync(object obj)
{
     return Task.FromResult(obj != null ? obj.ToString() : null);
}
```

This works fine, and it prints:

```
> 1
> _ (Wait for user interaction)
```

However, If I move my `Console.ReadLine()` to my anonymous action:

```
var tasks = new Task<string>[] { ToStringAsync(1) };
Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(r =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Result.First());
    Console.ReadLine();
});
```

This should produce the same exact output as before:

```
> 1
> _ (Wait for user interaction)
```

Instead, it doesn't wait for any input and the console application closes inmediately.

Why is `Console.ReadLine()` not working if I execute it inside `ContinueWith`?

Comment: In my opinion, the main thread doesn't wait any more instructions, so it exit the application because all the operations are done on an other thread

Comment: You need to capture the `Task` returned by `ContinueWith` and then wait on that so the main thread doesn't end first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ContinueWith` creates a new task that you also need to wait on, so just add a `Wait` after it.

```
var tasks = new Task<string>[] { ToStringAsync(1) };
Task.WhenAll(tasks)
    .ContinueWith(r =>
       {
            Console.WriteLine(r.Result.First());
            Console.ReadLine();
        })
    .Wait();
```

Now the main thread will wait for the continuation to finish before ending the program.

The reason that it "works" when the `ReadLine` is outside the continuation is because that is blocking the main thread, but you could potentially press enter fast enough that it would still end the program before the `WriteLine` occurs depending on how long the `tasks` take.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example it's not `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` but `Console.ReadLine()` waits for callback `Task` to complete. Method `WhenAll()` doesn't wait for `.ContinueWith()` as it's separate task that doesn't exist in `tasks` array.

In your second scenario `WhenAll` waits for both tasks to complete but when they are your program finishes execution.

Don't forget that if you execute `Console.ReadLine()` asynchronously it'll block the `Thread` in which it's executed, and it's not the Main thread this time. It also not be awaited and if in your second scenario you'll add `Thread.Sleep(5000);` to the end of `Main` method it'll wait for 5 seconds allowing user to enter text but then it finishes regardless of fact whether or not the user pressed 'enter'.

Short example when ReadLine is not waited :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t = new Task(() => { Console.ReadLine(); Console.WriteLine("You pressed enter"); });

        t.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

// executes only for 5 seconds